How do I properly use relative import in python to execute modules
I have the following file structure:
.
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── package1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   ├── module2.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │       └── module1.cpython-310.pyc
    ├── package2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module_r.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │       └── module_r.cpython-310.pyc
    └── __pycache__
        └── __init__.cpython-310.pyc

This is the code inside modules/package1/module1.py:
def func():
    print("the function was called")

and this is the code inside modules/package2/module_r.py:
from ..package1.module1 import func

func()

Also, this is the code inside main.py:
from modules.package2 import module_r 

When I execute the main file using the command: python3 main.py I get the expected result printed to the terminal ("the function was called") However, when I try to run  python3 modules/package2/module_r.py I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/santiago/Documents/test-python-packages/modules/package2/module_r.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..package1.module1 import func
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I have also tried absolute imports and this code:
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from modules.package1.module1 import func


but I get the same result. How can I properly import my packages so that I can both import them from the main file and execute them as a script?

I found a way to run ur code.
This is the original web where I found the solution.
In the ".", do cd ..
Then do python3 -m try.modules.package2.module_r
The reason of the error is that u are just running a single python file, not a python project. So there is no relation between the files.
result

Your absolute import should look like this
I replaced . with 123 and opened it as a workspace.
import sys
# sys.path.append('e:\\Desktop\\123\\modules')
# sys.path.append('./modules')

import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from package1.module1 import func    # There's no `modules.` here.

